# MYSQLI UPDATE syntax error

Tags: php, syntax

I am receiving the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'long='-96.7812', label='abc' WHERE id='2'' at line 1

Here is my code:

```
$db=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
session_start();
$sql="UPDATE locations SET name='$_POST[modname]', lat='$_POST[modlat]', long='$_POST[modlong]', label='$_POST[modlab]' WHERE id='$_SESSION[locnid]'";
echo $sql;
if (!mysqli_query($db,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
}
echo "1 record modified";
mysqli_close($db);
```

The **$sql** string echoed is this:
`UPDATE locations SET name='Baylor', lat='32.7923', long='-96.7812', label='abc' WHERE id='2'`

I don't see anything wrong with that.
I tried escaping the values (didn't think it would help and it didn't):
`$sql="UPDATE locations SET name='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST[modname])."', lat='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST[modlat])."', long='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST[modlong])."', label='$_POST[modlab]' WHERE id='$_SESSION[locnid]'";`

I get the same error and the same $sql string echoed out.

Thought maybe it had to do with the decimal points messing up the $sql string assignment, but even with whole numbers I get the same error.

Please help - if you can spot what the syntax error could possible be!

Comment: You should **always** escape **any** variable from the user going into your SQL. In the second example `$_POST['modlab']` and `$_SESSION['locnid']` are both unescaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column name **`long`** you have used is a [`reserved word`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL , Enclose it in backticks !

See here [An exerpt from your query]

```
g($db, $_POST[modlat])."', `long`='".mysqli_real_es
                           ^    ^ ----- Enclose it like this
```

Comment: Yes, that worked, what a quick (and tricky - for me!) problem/fix.  This is my first time posting a question into this forum, I have found MANY answers in here before. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql="UPDATE locations SET name='$_POST[modname]', lat='$_POST[modlat]', `long`='$_POST[modlong]', label='$_POST[modlab]' WHERE id='$_SESSION[locnid]'";
```

The column name long is a reserved word in MySQL. It should be enclosed between backticks.

Comment: I have [**already**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22118858/1003917) mentioned that right ? ;)

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen your answer before submitting mine. You are 100% correct.